# Spring RMI error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiInvocationHandler

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, classloader, rmi

I am trying to create some beans using `Spring` and export them to RMI...

Here is my code:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
    <property name="serviceName" value="OfferService" />
    <property name="service" ref="offerService" />
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="ro.project.services.OfferService" />
    <property name="registryPort" value="1199" />
</bean>
```

I created a file called "policy.all" in my root folder and I am running my VM with that arguments but I still have this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiInvocationHandler (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
```

I don't know what to do... in linux, the exact same project is running ok (with jdk 1.7.0.4) but in windows not... in java 1.5 (windows) it's working.. but in java 1.7.0.4 (windows) it's not working...

**EDITED:**

My error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter#0' defined in class path resource [spring/services.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiInvocationHandler (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
```

After adding this lines:

```
if (System.getSecurityManager() == null)
{ 
    RMISecurityManager manager = new RMISecurityManager();
    System.setSecurityManager(manager); 
}
```

I have this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [spring/application-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring/application-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

The point here is not to install a security manager but to find the class. You are missing some JAR file from your deployment.

Comment: Check the comments under my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it still important, but i personally face today the same issue, and cannot find answer. I post it here, maybe it helps someone.

Solution: stop `rmiregistry` program, or pass Spring jars to `rmiregistry` with -J option. Simplest way just stop rmiregistry and allow Spring to start another one with all required classes. And don't set up `RMISecurityManager`.

Comment: Helped me with an issue with rmiregistry, i had to kill an old process with one of the rmiregistry which was dangling.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have this in a part of your code:

```
System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());
```

You can have another security manager as well, but there just has to be a security manager installed.

Actually the line I posted can be easily fired in the main class of a standalone desktop application, but I am not sure in your case. You should look for a configuration option doing this probably.

Comment: He doesn't need that at all. He needs to make the missing class available. He only needs that if he is also using the RMI Codebase feature to supply classes. No evidence of that here.

Comment: What about this at the endof the error message: "... (**no security manager**: RMI class loader disabled)"?

Comment: From Javadoc: " RMI's class loader will not download any classes from remote locations if no security manager has been set"

Comment: after adding this line I get this error: `Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [spring/application-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring/application-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
` ... I am using maven...

Comment: @vizier The actual problem here is a ClassNotFoundException. Unless he is using the codebase feature, which he hasn't mentioned, adding a security manager won't solve the problem. Period.

Comment: @EJP you are right, the visible problem is ClassNotFoundException, that's obvious, but we are looking for the root cause. What I am suggesting (SecurityManager issue) was the root cause of similar problems for a few cases in the past. That's why I am suggesting this.

Comment: @vizier And I am telling you you are mistaken, and I have also told you why.

Answer (score 0):

With Spring RMIServiceExporter, the Best Practice to manage correctly the RMI Registry is the use of RMIRegistryFactoryBean. To better permits you to understand, I paste an example of Spring configuration with a RemoteBean:

```
<bean id="RemoteServices" class="remote.RMIServicesImpl"/>
<bean id="RemoteRmiRegistry" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean">
        <property name="alwaysCreate" value="true" />
        <property name="port" value="1093"></property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
        <property name="service" ref="RemoteServices" />
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="remote.RemoteInterface" />
        <property name="serviceName" value="RemoteServices" />
        <property name="replaceExistingBinding" value="true"></property>
        <property name="registry" ref="RemoteRmiRegistry"></property>
    </bean>
```

In this way the RmiRegistryFactoryBean will manage autonomously everything about the RMI Socket Layer, and you don't need to stop the JVM, but simply redeploy it.

Please rate me if it works.